# App crashes when switching applications

Tags: crash, windows-phone-8.1

When you switch applications or by pressing the Windows button application terminates. But on the first page of this application does not occur. In debug mode, this also happens. The application consumes 28 megabytes of memory. So the system should not terminate it.
Using Prism for windows phone and Unity 3.5 prerelease.

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs cause GetNavigationState doesn't support serialization of a parameter type which was passed to Frame.Navigate.